# Rust: After parallelization with rayon, write out results in order without waiting until the end

Tags: rust, rayon

I am using rayon's `.par_bridge().for_each(|r| { do_work(r) } )` to run tasks in parallel for some iterator (specifically: [Records](https://docs.rs/bio/latest/bio/io/bed/struct.Records.html) from a bed file, but I don't think that matters). There could be up to ~700.000 tasks.

I want to print (stdout or to a file) the results of every call to do_work(), but do this printing only in the order of the original iterator. I could sort all output after all parallel jobs have been completed, but storing all results until the end will require much more memory. I could add `.enumerate()` to have an index for each item and print out the first one when it is done, storing the rest until it is their turn, but I am not sure how to best implement such a system, or if it is the best solution at all. What would you suggest?

Comment: `rayon` usually splits iterators in half. So, the first task in the second thread is basically the 350,000th task. If you will block waiting for the tasks before to complete before writing, you'll effectively disable the cost of parallelism. You can use a separate thread and send the result to it using a channel, but I'm not sure this will be significantly better than storing all results in a `Vec` and sorting it at the end.

Comment: Ah, I see. My question was under the assumption that 8 threads first work on tasks 1 to 8, and when the first one is done, it works on task 9. Okay, then this is not a viable approach it seems.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `.par_bridge()` doesn't and can't split its input in half, because an ordinary `Iterator` doesn't permit that. So in this case, it is possible.

Comment: @KevinReid Ah, right, I didn't see it's `par_bridge()`. It's less efficient, though :)

Answer (score 1):

As @ChayimFriedman mentioned, this isn't necessarily feasible because `rayon` likes to subdivide work starting in large chunks, so the order won't be friendly. However, *because* you are using `.par_bridge()`, Rayon must take items from the `Iterator` in order, so the order will be close to the original order. Therefore, it is feasible to recover the original order using a buffer and `.enumerate()`, without consuming large amounts of memory.

Here is a demonstration program.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::time::Duration;

use rand::Rng;
use rayon::prelude::{ParallelBridge, ParallelIterator};

fn main() {
    let data_source = (0..500u32).rev();

    // Channel with enough capacity to hold an item from each thread
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::sync_channel(std::thread::available_parallelism().map_or(8, |n| n.get()));

    rayon::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(move |_| {
            data_source
                .enumerate()
                .par_bridge()
                .map(|(i, value)| {
                    // pretend to do some work
                    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(
                        1000 + rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..10),
                    ));
                    (i, value)
                })
                .for_each_with(tx, |tx, pair| {
                    let _ = tx.send(pair);
                });
        });

        recover_order(rx, emit);
    });
}

fn emit(item: u32) {
    println!("done with {item}");
}

fn recover_order<T>(rx: mpsc::Receiver<(usize, T)>, mut op: impl FnMut(T)) {
    let mut next_index: usize = 0;
    let mut buffer: HashMap<usize, T> = HashMap::new();
    for (i, value) in rx {
        if i == next_index {
            op(value);
            next_index += 1;
            while let Some((_, value)) = buffer.remove_entry(&next_index) {
                op(value);
                next_index += 1;
            }
        } else {
            // Item is out of order
            buffer.insert(i, value);
        }
    }

    assert!(buffer.is_empty(), "channel closed with missing items");

    println!("Buffer capacity used: {}", buffer.capacity());
}
```

The `for_each_with()` transfers items from Rayon control to the channel, and the `recover_order()` function consumes the channel to call `emit()` with the items in proper order.

The use of `rayon::scope()` and `spawn()` allows the `for_each_with()` parallel iteration to run “in the background” on the existing Rayon thread pool, so that the current thread can handle the receiving directly.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to use so small capacity. It can defeat the purpose of parallelism by effectively serializing it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah, I had been thinking “the receiver will be much faster than the individual threads” but that's not necessarily true, and even if it is, contention for available channel capacity might still be an issue. I've updated it to use `available_parallelism()`. (Of course, if `emit` can't keep up with the per-thread work, then it will be the bottleneck no matter what; that's inherent to the problem, not something that can be addressed by choice of algorithm.)

Comment: The code above only works well if each job takes more or less the same duration. In a worst case scenario, if one job can blocked for significantly longer time than most others, it could cause the memory usage to balloon. In the example above, using a normal distribution instead of a uniform one, for the same [1000..1010] sleep range, the max number of buffered results jumps from ~20 to ~80 (16% of the total number of results). You can trigger an even worst case scenario by sleeping only for the job with value 499 (i.e. the first). Then the hashmap ends up storing all the results but one.

Comment: Also, it looks like the capacity can shrink after removing entries, so using that to measure how much was buffered is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version adapted from @kevin-reid's.
As mentioned in my comment to his post, with his code, if a thread is slow, the others will keep on working anyway, resulting in more and more data being stored in the buffer. In a worst case scenario, ***all*** the data can get stored in that buffer but the first.

My adaptation will block a thread from sending its result until it's its turn. This means that at most, there will be one result per thread in memory (plus whatever is waiting in the `sync_channel`).
The main drawback is the need for the `Mutex` and `notify_all`, which can have a significant cost when the work can be done quickly.

It's also possible to combine both answers to allow the threads to run ahead but within reason, but I leave that as an exercise .

```rust
use std::{
    sync::{mpsc, Arc, Condvar, Mutex},
    time::Duration,
};

use rand::Rng;
use rayon::prelude::{ParallelBridge, ParallelIterator};

fn main() {
    let data_source = (0..500u32).rev();

    // Channel with enough capacity to hold an item from each thread
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::sync_channel(std::thread::available_parallelism().map_or(8, |n| n.get()));

    let gate = Arc::new((Mutex::new(0), Condvar::new()));

    rayon::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(move |_| {
            data_source
                .enumerate()
                .par_bridge()
                .map(|(i, value)| {
                    // pretend to do some work
                    // For worst case scenario, replace with:
                    //    if i == 0 { std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)); }
                    std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(
                        1000 + rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..10),
                    ));

                    (i, value)
                })
                .for_each_with((tx, gate), |(tx, gate), (i, value)| {
                    let (lock, cond) = &**gate;

                    {
                        let mut guard = cond.wait_while(lock.lock().unwrap(), |v| *v < i).unwrap();
                        let _ = tx.send((i, value));
                        *guard = i + 1;
                    }

                    cond.notify_all();
                });
        });

        recover_order(rx, emit);
    });
}

fn emit(item: u32) {
    println!("done with {item}");
}

fn recover_order<T>(rx: mpsc::Receiver<(usize, T)>, mut op: impl FnMut(T)) {
    let mut next_index: usize = 0;
    for (i, value) in rx {
        if i != next_index {
            // Item is out of order
            panic!("Wrong index {i}, expected {next_index}");
        }
        op(value);
        next_index += 1;
    }
}
```